# How to check in neat way if collection contains an object which's one property is equal to the object passed to Contains method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have a model class:

```
  public class AuthorizationToView {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Person CustomerToVisit { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
  }
```

The `ApplicationDbContext db` has a property: `public DbSet<AuthorizationToView> AuthorizationsToView { get; set; }`

And the  `ApplicationUser` has a property `public virtual ICollection<AuthorizationToView> PersonsPermittedToView { get; set; }`

**ISSUE:**
Now in one place in code I try to check if `user` have inside hist `public virtual ICollection<AuthorizationToView> PersonsPermittedToView { get; set; }` an `AuthorizationToView` which has certain `Person` as property and if not return BadRequest.

I try this:

```
 if (User.IsInRole("RegularUser")) {
                var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                if (!user.PersonsPermittedToView.Contains(new AuthorizationToView { CustomerToVisit = person })) {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }              
            }
```

but unfortunately `!user.PersonsPermittedToView.Contains(new AuthorizationToView { CustomerToVisit = person })` is always true.

I could override `Equals` method but I am affraid that it will confuse Entity Framework.

Comment: I think you should rather use `.Any()` instead of `.Contains()`

Comment: @DavidG Could you please show how? I thought that I might must use LINQ but don't know how in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `Person` has a primary key property called `Id`, this is how I would achieve the same thing:

```
if (User.IsInRole("RegularUser"))
{
    var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

    if (!user.PersonsPermittedToView.Any(pptv => 
              pptv.CustomerToVisit.PersonToVisit.Id == person.Id))
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just compare the person directly, rather than creating the new AuthorizationToView, like this:

```
if (!user.PersonsPermittedToView.Select(a=>a.CustomerToVisit).Contains(person)) 
{
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

Or if you actually should be checking on Id, use:

```
if (!user.PersonsPermittedToView.Select(a=>a.CustomerToVisit.Id).Contains(person.Id)) 
{
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```